# How to solve the communication issue between device and user

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do communication between device and user.Like a device will ask question "How are you" and if user will reply "I am fine" device will alert "OK great"at same time device will ask second question "How was your day" and user will reply "Good".I have tried and almost work have been completed but a small issue which i am facing that device repeat the second question multiple time and reply back alert"OK" multiple time.
Here is my code..

```js
var text = 'How are you?';
var question2='How was your day?';
var response;
 
// ask the problem
ask(text, function (err, result) {
 if (err) 
  {
     speak('Could not listen');
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Could not listen.';
  } 
  else 
  {
     var answer = result.transcript;
     if (answer == 'good')
        { 
          alert('OK good');
            ///function calling
            ask2(question2,function (err1, result1) 
             {   
                 if (err1)                
                 {
                   speak2('Could not listen inner');
                 } 

                else 

                {
                     var answer1 = result1.transcript;
                     if (answer1 == 'Good')
                        {
                         alert("OK");
                        } 
                    else 
                        {
                            alert('OHoo');
                        }
        
                }
             })
   }
            else 
                
                { 
            response = 'Oh!';
            speak(response);
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response;
                }
       
  }

})
 
 
// ask a question and get an answer
function ask(text, callback) {
    // ask question
    speak(text, function () {
      
        // get answer
        var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.interimResults =true;
 
        recognition.onend = function (e) {
            if (callback) {
                callback('no results');
            }
        };
 
        recognition.onresult = function (e) {
            // cancel onend handler
            recognition.onend = null;
            if (callback) {
                callback(null, {
                    transcript: e.results[0][0].transcript,
                    confidence: e.results[0][0].confidence
                });
            }
        }
 
        // start listening

        recognition.start();
    });
}
 
 
// say a message
function speak(text, callback) {
    var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    u.text = text;
    u.lang = 'en-US';
 
    u.onend = function () {
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    };
 
    u.onerror = function (e) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(e);
        }
    };
 
    speechSynthesis.speak(u);
}


// say a question 2
function speak2(question2, callback) {
   
    var u2 = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    u2.text= question2;
    u2.lang = 'en-US';
 
    u2.onend = function () {
        if (callback) {
            callback();
        }
    };
 
    u2.onerror = function (e) {
        if (callback) {
            callback(e);
        }
    };
 
    speechSynthesis.speak(u2);


}


function ask2(question2, callback) {
// var question2='What did you eat?';
    // ask question
    speak2(question2, function () {  
         var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        recognition.continuous = true;
        recognition.interimResults =true;
 
        recognition.onend = function (e) {
            if (callback) {   
                callback('no results');
            }
        };
    // wait(2000);
        recognition.onresult = function (e) {
            // cancel onend handler
            recognition.onend = null;
            if (callback) {
                callback(null, {
                    transcript: e.results[0][0].transcript,
                    confidence: e.results[0][0].confidence
                });
            }
        }

        recognition.start();
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Math Quiz</title>
    <!-- <link href="mathquiz.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->


</head>
<body>

 
    <output id="result" ></output>
    <a href="mathQuiz.html">Ask Question</a>
    <script src="mathQuiz.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be good if you could reproduce the problem in a testing environment such as jsfiddle.net, and post here only the minimal relevant code

Comment: Yes I have write my code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well, can you provide us the link so we can test it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xat01obz/

Comment: This is builtin method for recognization thats why i have just created object in speak() and speak2() function.

Comment: Feels like once you have processed answer you ought to set it back to an empty string

Comment: I noticed that when second question starts .The recognition function is still working.Is there any code which stop the recognition when device speak second question and just start the recognition when 
question complete.

Comment: Finally i have solved my problem